# @font-face producing radically different results in browsers

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Just grabbed a `@font-face` package for our website, and put in the following CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CartoGothicProLight';
    src: url('fonts/cartogothicpro-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/cartogothicpro-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/cartogothicpro-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/cartogothicpro-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/cartogothicpro-light-webfont.svg#CartoGothicProLight') format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Unfortunately the results are really different in every browser. Only Firefox gets it right on both Windows and OSX; the others are all over the place.

Here's what we're seeing:

[image]

Any tips or indicators of what might be wrong/browser's behaviours with fonts would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Talking from personal experience.

`@font-face` actually works ok and also the technique you used is ok - it's more of a font file problem.

Some fonts will render ok cross browsers (read "result is pleasing and readable for the eye") and some will just get the [font hinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) all wrong. I usually try to use few similar fonts and see which one produces best results cross browsers since not all browsers use same process of hinting.

It also depends on quality of the font - some are just not intended to be used at smaller sizes, badly designed - each font file comes with it's own hinting instructions which define how should pixels be turned on and off on different font sizes to display the font in a most readable way.

I hope I gave you some insight of what could be going on altough I can hardly provide you a fix for this exact example.